# Retrieve data from both tables one to many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

I've two table `Rule` and `Action`.

One rule can have many actions

lets say Action  have a1,a2,a3 3 rows related to One Rule

then i want to select

```
r1.*, a1.name, a1.createdon, a1.modifiedon, 
      a2.name, a2.createdon, a2.modifiedon, 
      a3.name, a3.createdon, a3.modifiedon
```

but r2 may do not have any rule. 
so it will select data from `Rule` only

result

```
r*
```

I've written this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Rule RB 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT RelatedRuleId
    FROM Action_ GROUP BY RelatedRuleId
) R ON R.RelatedRuleId =  RB.RuleId
```

this is not giving me correct result.

**how can i pull this? I want one rule row with multiple actions in same row.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not achievable in plain SQL, because the number of columns in the result set has to be known before issuing the query. In your requirement, the number of columns is determined by the content of the tables. This is not possible in SQL.

What you *can* do, is either query the number of actions beforehand and dynamically build the SQL with a suitable number of columns in your application code or use `group_concat` to concat the result into one column like this:

```
select rule.id, 
       rule.name, 
       group_concat(concat(action.name, ';', 
                           action.createdon, ';', 
                           action.modifiedon)) as actions
from rule 
inner join action on rule.id = action.rule_id
group by rule.id
```

(see also the SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94596/6 to play with it)

This yields something like:

```
id  name    actions
1   rule1   action1;2016-01-05;2016-02-06,action2;2016-01-06;2016-02-05
2   rule2   action3;2016-01-12;2016-02-19
```

Then you need to parse the resulting column by splitting it at the separators `,` and `;`.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it with simple left join

```
 SELECT RB.* ,
      GROUP_CONCAT(R.name), 
      GROUP_CONCAT(R.createdon),
      GROUP_CONCAT(R.modifiedon)
    FROM Rule RB 
    LEFT JOIN  Action R ON R.RelatedRuleId =  RB.RuleId 
    GROUP BY RB.RuleId
```

Comment: No, i want One Rule Id and All action details in one row. not in separate rows

Comment: There are 3 tables he wants to join `a1 and a2 and a3`

Comment: @UnknownUser : Updated answer . you can use group concat

Comment: @Mahesh I got your point but I do not want comma separated values I want different columns